# facebook image sharing using facebook api not working with other account in android

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

In my current project I've on task that is image sharing from our app to **facebook**. I've created project in my developer's account also.

In my app image sharing working with developers account. And I've made my developers account as public. Login is working but sharing is not working.

For every time it's going oncancel method in registerCallback.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");


//this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI

manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

manager.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        sharePhotoToFacebook();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        System.out.println("onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        System.out.println("onError");
    }
});
```

Comment: for that you have to review your app to facebook or  you can add tester and developer from your account

Comment: but at time of live scenario what i have to do?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review checkout this link

Answer (score 0):

In case of sharing anything to facebook you need to submit your app to facebook for review.

check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs#faq_959251624152434) for more.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) is the whole guideline for app review process.